# How to extract URL parameters on 404 Error in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, get

I have my htaccess redirecting to a error404.php but I want that PHP file to be able to extract the original url parameters.

For example:

```
http://mywebsite.com/unknownfile.php?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

I've tried `$_GET['param1']` but that's empty. The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` just shows error404.php

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the redirect implemented? Are you rewriting the request or actually redirecting (i.e. a Location header to your PHP script)?

Comment: .htaccess has this content only:
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

Comment: It's an htaccess redirect (for a 404 not found)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access original URL via `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

**For example:** requesting URL `/hihi/meow?key=rumba` which does not exists. The `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` will have that string, which you can parse with [parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) function to split into parts and use other functions (like `explode()` to get to individual query strung parameters.

Comment: just curious why PHP doesn't populate $_GET in this case, it seems very non-intuitive.

Comment: @Michael According to php.net: `$_SERVER` *is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are **created by the web server.***, while `$_GET` *is an associative array of **variables passed to the current script** via the URL parameters.* So to answer your question: `$_GET` contains variables passed to the CURRENT script and `$_SERVER` contains variables that the server itself creates. Since the error script fallback (i.e.404) and the current script are different, `$_GET` will not be populated with the variables passed to the first page

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect this info will only be present in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: Forgot to say I've tried that too
$test = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "test = $test </br>";
But I get nothing
test =

Comment: so then how do you redirect ?

Comment: unknownfile.php being access does not exist and my htaccess has a redirect for 404 not found to error404.php.

Comment: this doesnt anwer the question on HOW YOU REDIRECT. post the line/s you wrote in the .htaccess