# Php redirect 404 to closest url in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, http-status-code-404

Google has picked up around 30,000 404 URL's in Google Webmaster Tools and I've been manually redirecting a lot of them and using some regex/explode() to cope with some of them but I can't seem to make rules that cover it all.

When a 404 is about to occur I would like my 404 php script to check my table of existing urls for the closest match and redirect to it.

For example if the bad url is "http://www.example.com/category-somenonexistingpart-someactuallyexistingpart-somejibberish-1234.htm" I would like my database to return the existing url that resembles the bad url the most = "http://www.example.com/category-someactuallyexistingpart.htm"

Can this be done? Is it a good or bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a 404.php page and have .htaccess redirect all 404's here. Then, using `$_SERVER` ( can't remember the specific key ), you can parse the requested URI, split it, then search the DB... you may notice an increased load on the DB, however.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "split it, then search the db" part? I've already setup the script to do some manual rewrites.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823721/how-to-extract-url-parameters-on-404-error-in-php

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try splitting the url with explode() and search for the individual strings and get the url that matches the most substrings. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this with a single sql query though - or looping the exploded array into a query that returns a single URL. I'll try this strategy but any help will be much appreciated :)